# Multicast data cannot be received by programs

Tags: wireshark, multicast

[Connection Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIlDh.png)

As given above, we connected two computers with one ethernet cable. Then using different programs we tried to sent data using as unicast,broadcast and multicast. However, we could not achieve to sent data as multicast. I mean, we can capture the data using wireshark, however both vlc,ffplay could not achieve to receive data.

- We disabled firewalls of computers.
- We achieved to send unicast and broadcast.
- Wireshark can capture multicast data and there are not any checksum issues.
- We use 239.5.5.5 as multicast address.
- We checked ttl of packets.
- We used different computers, but we get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We forgot to turn off other interfaces in the computer including wifi and virtual machine interfaces. After turning off other interfaces, we are able to get multicast stream from Ethernet interface.